# Conditional statements not working properly

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, arduino-uno, pyserial

I wrote this script in python to send data over serial communication to my Arduino UNO. It uses the OpenCV library to process a binary image and takes decisions based on the position of the detected object.

Here's the script:-

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM3',9600,writeTimeout = 0)
def f(x): return
cv2.namedWindow('Thresholding Control')

# create trackbars for color change
cv2.createTrackbar('High H','Thresholding Control',179,179, f)
cv2.createTrackbar('Low H','Thresholding Control',0,179, f)
cv2.createTrackbar('High S','Thresholding Control',255,255, f)
cv2.createTrackbar('Low S','Thresholding Control',0,255, f)
cv2.createTrackbar('High V','Thresholding Control',255,255, f)
cv2.createTrackbar('Low V','Thresholding Control',0,255, f)
cv2.createTrackbar('Guassian Blur','Thresholding Control',0,99, f)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
  ret, image = cap.read()
  HSV = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
  # Getting trackbar values
  highH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('High H','Thresholding Control')
  lowH = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Low H','Thresholding Control')
  highS = cv2.getTrackbarPos('High S','Thresholding Control')
  lowS = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Low S','Thresholding Control')
  highV = cv2.getTrackbarPos('High V','Thresholding Control')
  lowV = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Low V','Thresholding Control')
  # Thresholding the image.
  thresh = cv2.inRange( HSV, (lowH, lowS, lowV), (highH, highS, highV))
  blurVal = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Guassian Blur','Thresholding Control')
  if(blurVal%2==0):
      blurVal=blurVal+1
  thresh_smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (blurVal, blurVal), 0)
  #Defining the kernel to be used for Morphological ops.
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
  # Applying Opening and Closing.
  thresh_smooth = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh_smooth,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel)
  thresh_smooth = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh_smooth, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

  eleR = np.count_nonzero(thresh_smooth[0:480, 320:550])
  eleL = np.count_nonzero(thresh_smooth[0:480, 0:320])
  eleO = np.count_nonzero(thresh_smooth[0:480, 550:640])

  if (eleL>eleR and eleL>eleO and eleL!= (eleR+eleO)):
     cv2.putText(image,"Left Turn", (320,240), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 255)
     ser.write('L')

  if (eleO>eleR and eleO>eleL):
     cv2.putText(image,"Right Turn", (240,320), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 255)
     ser.write('R')

  else:
     cv2.putText(image,"Straight", (240,320), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 255)
     ser.write('S')

  cv2.imshow("BGR", image)
  cv2.imshow("Thresholded", thresh_smooth)
  print ser.readline();
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The problem here are the `if` statements. Out of the three conditions, no matter which condition is true, only the value 'S' (in the `else` statement) is sent over serial, as confirmed by the `print ser.readline()` command. Then all of a sudden the value of any of the `if` blocks might be sent and then the same value just goes on, no matter what position in the image the object is. The `cv2.putText` commands work as expected, it's only the `ser.write` that's causing the problem.

I tried putting `elif` in place of the second `if`, also tried putting the `continue` statement in each of the conditional blocks, which for some reason crashes the script during runtime. None of them helped. I have no idea how to fix this bug.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Tried increasing the baud rate to 115200, didn't work. Put a capacitor between RESET and GND pins, didn't work.

Comment: Before your if suites, print `ele0, eleR` and `eleL`.  Be sure your tests make sense

Comment: @joelgoldstick I did, got some values, every condition worked accordingly. They do make sence.

Comment: Sorry, I missed some.  Removed comment

Comment: No prob @joelgoldstick ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. Putting what I did here, for people who are curious and for those who need help.

It was probably the Arduino, autoresetoverserialcomm, for some reason the Arduino auto-resets whenever you send a value over the serial comm to the Arduino from a computer, not from the Serial port (obviously). I knew of this earlier, and another one of my script which also sends data to the Arduino was working fine with this setup.

What I did? I just put a 10µ capacitor between the RESET and the GND pins. That didn't work initially, but I tried putting the +ve of the capacitor in the GND pin and -ve in the RESET pin and voila! The script started working just fine.

I guess this wasn't a programming issue at all, but an issue of the Arduino and the script not being able to contact each other.

I still am not sure as to what was causing the problem or whether what I have done is a *permanent* fix, or even a fix at all, but my problem seems to have been solved. I'll keep updating the post.

Suggestions and discussions are always welcome!